# How to check in an NSAssert of an variable is (null)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

the console prints me (null) for an variable that should not be, so I want to put an assert there just for fun:

```
NSAssert(myVar, @"myVar was (null)!");
```

what's the trick here?
this (null) thing doesn't seem to be "nil", right? How can I check for it? I want to assume that the var is set properly and not nil, not null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `myVar` is of type `id` (or any object type), use

```
NSAssert(myVar != nil, @"")
```

If the assertion passes, you should be able to print `myVar` to the console with

```
NSLog(@"myVar = %@", myVar);
```

As a side note, `nil==null`, (both are `#defined` as `__DARWIN_NULL` which is `#defined` `((void *)0)`). If you try to use `NSLog` to print the `-description` of a `nil` (or `NULL`) object reference you get "(null)"

Answer (score -1):

do [myVar isEqualToClass:[NSNull null]] this returns yes if it is NSNull, if its nil  you can do if(myVar==nil)

Comment: it is not,  therefore i gave two ways to compare if

Answer (score -1):

I usually do

```
if (object != nil)
  doSomething(object);
else
  NSLog("bad object!");
```